# Minimize/Maximize current window keyboard shortcut

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, window-manager, ubuntu-13.04

Are there any Keyboard Shortcuts for maximizing, minimizing and resizing the current window?

I am on Ubuntu 13.04, Gnome-latest version.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try that:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> Minimize current window.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> Maximize the current window.

If you prefer to create custom shortcuts see this [article](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/3.5/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html.en).

Edit:

Go to: `Applications` > `System Tools` > `System Settings` > `Keyboards` > `Shortcuts`.
Choose the **Navigation** option, then just add. Or:

[image]

[image]

Comment: `Alt+F9/F10` doesn't work for me, but thanks for the link. Add the information about seeing the set shortcuts and I will accept the answer. :-) For example I have set `CTRL+Super+UP/DOWN`

Comment: Added information. :-)

Comment: Didn't work for me either, nor was there an option explicitly for "minimize", but `Super (aka "Windows") + H` "hides" one window, which seems to be the same thing. Thanks for the suggestion to look in keyboards -- still gets the job done 10 years out.

Answer (score 47):

In Ubuntu 14 work for me

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> to maximize.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> to minimize.

<kbd>Super</kbd> aka <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>

Comment: Same for Ubuntu 16

Comment: To organize the window left or right, use `Ctrl` + `Super` + `Left`/`Right`.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 20.04 and above:

| Keystrokes | Command |
| --- | --- |
| <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> *or* <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> | maximize the current window (if not maximized) unmaximize the current window (if maximized) <sup>***** *see note*</sup> |
| <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> *or* <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> | minimize the current window |

***** *If a window is maximized, the same keyboard shortcut used to maximize a window will instead restore the window to its original unmaximized size.*
[Ubuntu 20.04:  Maximize and unmaximize a window](https://help.ubuntu.com/20.04/ubuntu-help/shell-windows-maximize.html)

Comment: In Ubuntu 22 there is not such option in `Settings`  menu, `Keyboard` tab, while `Hide window` is given by `Super` + `H`
Could you provide a source for the minimise keystroke mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the comment by https://superuser.com/a/1776234/1794113, it worked for me.

The commands <kbd>SUPER</kbd>(WinKey) + <kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> are used to minimize or maximize windows previously displayed ("show Desktop"). You can try that out with several windows maximized.

The command <kbd>SUPER</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> is used to minimize a single window ("hide window").

If you want to hide the current displayed content in a monitor, you can use <kbd>SUPER</kbd> + <kbd>PgDown</kbd> or <kbd>SUPER</kbd> + <kbd>PgUp</kbd> to bring it back up. As far as I know, this only works in the main display.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a keyboard shortcut to maximize all windows. That would be very useful. The most approximate solution for this would be maybe using <kbd>SUPER</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> and then <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> or <kbd>SUPER</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> to maximize the latest window.

Additional: This command may be useful, too: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>SUPER</kbd> + <kbd>sideArrow</kbd>. It will move an opened window into another monitor.

Comment: I noted that the key combinations `Super+PgUp` and `Super+PgDown` are [documented by Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-workspaces-switch.html)  as switching to the next workspace (left or right) whereas [your answer](https://superuser.com/a/1781382/) as well as [alex-fedotov's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1774965) describe the key combination more akin to hiding a window.  Is the disconnect tied to whether a user only has 1 workspace or is it something else?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! 
With respect to `Super+PgUp` and `Super+PgDown`, it's actually like that but at the same time it looks like if it was hiding the content. In the case that there are two monitors connected to the PC, only the main monitor workspace is hidden and the other one remains the same. At least that's what works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Under Ubunutu 22.04,

In `Settings` > `Keyboard` > `Keyboard Shortcuts` > `Windows`

<kbd>Super</kbd>  +  <kbd>Up</kbd>  : Maximize window

<kbd>Super</kbd>  +  <kbd>H</kbd>  : Hide window

Then *Hide window* stands for *minimize* here.

Comment: Finally, an answer that fully works on Ubuntu 22.04. (Alt+F10 works for me, too, but not Alt+F9.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you looking for this `SUPER + H`.

The similar one is `SUPER + D`

Good luck!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What do you mean by *similar*? Please [edit] your answer to explain what these keyboard shortcuts do actually.

Answer (score -1):

Addition: I just discovered that ...

on **Ubuntu 22.04** (*Jammy Jellyfish*)

...there still ***is*** an option to shrink the window of a running application so that it would only stay marked (with a dot) on the dock in the same way that it would when you clicked "_" on the upper-right corner of the window in the past. The shortcut is:

`Win` + `PgDown` -> Application window shrinks to an icon in the dock

`Win` + `PgUp` or click on this icon in the dock  -> Application window expands

Comment: Does not work on Ubuntu 22.04, however `Super` + `H` minimise window, or "hide" the window.

Comment: Your key is named differently than my key, that's what 'doesn't work'.

Comment: please provide a ref or a screen of the shortcut

Comment: This does not work for me on Ubuntu 22.04. Your shortcuts switch me to the previous or next virtual desktop.